# Maven (Tycho) cannot resolve OSGi Core bundle

Tags: maven, osgi, tycho

I have a dependency on "org.osgi:osgi.core" (7.0.0) in my POM. The reason is that I need access to the "org.osgi.framework" package. I am using Maven (3.6) and Tycho (1.5.1) for building. The build platform runs Debian 10 and Java 11.

I get the following error:

```
Missing requirement: osgi.core 7.0.0.201802012106 requires 'osgi.unresolvable; (&(!(must.not.resolve=*))(must.not.resolve=*))' but it could not be found
```

However, if I remove the dependency I get the following error:

```
Missing requirement: my.bundle 0.0.0.qualifier requires 'java.package; org.osgi.framework 1.7.0' but it could not be found
```

What is going wrong? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I get the following error:

Missing requirement: osgi.core 7.0.0.201802012106 requires 'osgi.unresolvable; (&(!(must.not.resolve=*))(must.not.resolve=*))' but it could not be found
```

The "companion jars" are not meant for runtime and since resolving is a runtime operation (even when performed during build, i.e. for deployment purposes) should not be included (and are therefore marked with the `unresolvable` requirement).

```
However, if I remove the dependency I get the following error:
Missing requirement: my.bundle 0.0.0.qualifier requires 'java.package; org.osgi.framework 1.7.0' but it could not be found
```

This means you have no runtime framework available! Add a runtime dependency on the equinox framework (not intentionally being biased, but since you're using tycho I'm assuming eclipse/equinox landscape. If you have Apache Felix framework available to p2/tycho then use that if you like):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
    <version>3.x.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
// of course use tycho mechanism for above.
```

Comment: Thanks, Raymond! Does this also relate to "org.osgi:osgi.cmpn"? Should I remove this dependency too? Should I add "org.eclipse.osgi.services" or the individual "org.osgi.service.*" to my (parent) POM? Are the individual "org.osgi.service.*" also required at runtime (on classpath or installed to osgi?). Will "org.eclipse.osgi" start without "org.eclipse.osgi.services" on the classpath or installation as bundle?

Comment: __Q:__ Should I add "org.eclipse.osgi.services" or the individual "org.osgi.service.*" to my (parent) POM? Are the individual "org.osgi.service.*" also required at runtime (on classpath or installed to osgi?).

__A:__ In general you compile against APIs and run against implementations. For instance you should compile against `org.osgi.service.component.annotations` and run (i.e. resolve) against `org.apache.felix.scr`. Avoid `org.eclipse.osgi.services`. I think Equinox project has been trying for a while to divest itself from it.

Comment: To clarify, some implementations package the APIs, others rely on the API bundle being deployed:
__e.g. A:__ `org.apache.felix.scr` embeds the API for DS (i.e. `org.osgi.service.component.*`) __e.g. B:__ `org.apache.aries.cdi.extender` relies on `org.osgi.service.cdi` being deployed with it.